# How to overwrite current document mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregation command and need to overwrite the current documents;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
        $project: {
            class: "Apples",
            imageUrl: { $substr: [ "$imageUrl", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$imageUrl", "\n" ] } ] }
        }
    }
])

Collection:
{
id:...
class:"Apples"
imageUrl:"..."
}
```

There are multiple documents that need to be updated. this is what i currently have appended to the above command but its not working.

```
.forEach( doc => db.product.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { imageUrl: doc.imageUrl } } ) )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either run [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) (**replaces** entire existing collection with aggregation result):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            class: "Apples",
            imageUrl: { $substr: [ "$imageUrl", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$imageUrl", "\n" ] } ] }
        }
    },
    { $out: "collection" }
])
```

or new [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) operator ("merges" aggregation results with existing documents):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            class: "Apples",
            imageUrl: { $substr: [ "$imageUrl", 0, { $indexOfBytes: [ "$imageUrl", "\n" ] } ] }
        }
    },
    { $merge: { into: "collection", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
])
```

Comment: they are only 2 fields of ~10. i tried the first one but it replaced everything with just those two fields.

Comment: @Kingswoop use `$addFields` instead of `$project` (will replace existing fields)